# Can I pre-scale and cache Images?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-development

I have a game which is drawing 324 tiles to an HTML5 canvas at 60 frames per second.
It was working great when the tilesize was set to a fixed number of pixels and matched the pixels of the source image file.
I updated the game to resize to the user's screen upon load.  Everything still works fine, but the game has a bit of lag now.  My assumption is that this is caused by the resizing of the images on every draw.
I am using the drawImage() method as follows:

```
ctx.drawImage(image, xCoord, yCoord, tileSize, tileSize);
```

I have tried modifying the width and height of each of the tile images after the new tileSize is obtained:

```
tiles.forEach((tile) => {
   tile.image.height = tileSize;
   tile.image.width = tileSize;
}
```

The values are retained in the object, but if I call drawObject without specifying width and height, they are drawn back at their naturalHeight and naturalWidth.

How can I resize the images and store the resized versions for use throughout the program?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.